# On which basis correlation matrix take features in python?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I have 80 columns and if i do correlation matrix for removing the features then correlation matrix do not take all columns, why?

Comment: Minimal reproducible code, please. Also, please clarify your question: you make the correlation matrix (how exactly?). Does it have only one row? If so, how removing features is related to this problem? Maybe, the column names disappeared and you want to recover them. It's unclear what is the problem.

Comment: 1400 rows and 80 columns. I am working on House Prices: Advanced Regression Techniques data.

Answer (score 0):

The correlation matrix will work only for numerical features. It automatically drops the object types. . So make sure you convert the columns to their appropriate types.

Check out my Kaggle notebook here if you are interested:
https://www.kaggle.com/ajaysamp/boston-housing-price-end-to-end-eda-model